# Post request saving only versionKey with Mongoose and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to save a number and a few string values to a MongoDB and even though the code makes perfect sense to me, returns no errors and creates an entry in the database, all I get is just a versionKey, something like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58052711f319bc041c5ebdac"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I thought I'd try just saving the number and the title first to see if they get saved, but they don't, as you can see above.
Every RESTful API and Express "post" request tutorial and answer I find seems to do it differently!

Also, is it supposed to show the res.json in plaintext for me to format or render somehow, or is it supposed to show the value of the property `message:`?

Here is the code

```
// modules =======================================================
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


// configuration =================================================
const db = require('./config/db')


// mongoose ======================================================
mongoose.connect(db.url)

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  number:Number,
  title:String,
  body:String,
  images:String
}, { collection: 'posts' })

const posts = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)


// routes ========================================================
app.post('/api/post', function(req, res) {
  var post = new posts()
  post.number = req.body.number
  post.title = req.body.title
  post.save(function(err) {
    if (err) res.send(err)
    res.json({ message: 'Post saved'})
  })
})
```

Here is my HTML5 form

```
<form action="/api/post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <label for="number">Post Number:</label>
  <input type="number" name="number" size="2" placeholder="required" required /><br />

  <label for="title">Title:</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="optional" /><br />

  <label for="body">Text:</label><br />
  <textarea name="body" cols="80" rows="20" placeholder="optional"></textarea><br />

  <label for="images">Images:</label>
  <input type="text" name="images" placeholder="optional" />
  <span class="form-hint">Comma separated file names, e.g. image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.png</span><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My middleware that comes just before the routes in server.js

```
// middleware ====================================================
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })) // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')) // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) // set static files location
```

Comment: First, for troubleshooting the issue, have you logged out `req.body` to make sure you're getting the properties you want?  Second, for the `res.json()` you will get a json object back that looks like `{ message: "Post saved"}` and that's it

Comment: Empty object {} logged from req.body and every property like req.body.number is logged as undefined.

Comment: I have just edited my question to include the middleware I use in server.js. Maybe something there is not parsing things right?

Comment: So that tells you your form is not sending the data properly.  You may just log out `req` to see if you can find the data in it, otherwise you'll have to look at what you are doing to send the data (ajax calls, or some other form of posting the data, whatever you are doing).

Comment: I found that it was `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form. Once I removed that, the request is received and saved to the database properly. Thank you!
That part confused me in an example. I think I pieced together multiple examples since they were all different and the first one I followed didn't work as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question, the encoding must match what you have Express parsing (in this case it wasn't `multipart/form-data` but `application/json`, `'application/vnd.api+json'`, and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Removing the encoding type you were specifying fixes that.

Second, the response will be a simple JSON object:

```
{
    "message": "Post saved"
}
```